# What is the meaning of $(\nabla w)^{\bot}$?

Tags: tensors, fluid-dynamics

[image]

I don't understand the meaning of $(\nabla w)^{\bot}$ in the picture below even in dimension two. I know that $\nabla^{\bot}:=(-\partial_2, \partial_1)$, but how to define $A^{\bot}$ for a matrix $A$. And I fail to obtain the formula (1.6) by integration by parts.

Comment: This is strange indeed. Usually the rate-of-strain tensor is given as $\boldsymbol \epsilon=\frac{1}{2}\nabla\boldsymbol u+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\boldsymbol u)^\intercal$
So maybe they just used the wrong symbol for the transpose? What is the source this is taken from?

Comment: @K.defaoite， page 4 in Partial Differential Equations in
Fluid Mechanics Edited by CHARLES L. FEFFERMAN, JAMES C. ROBINSON, and JOS´E L. RODRIGO.

Comment: Yeah, I've researched it all I can. I'm pretty certain it's just a typo.